# Join Domain from VM

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, domain, vmware-player

I have two VMs running on VMWare Player.
I use NAT adapter settings. The host machine for VMs is running on corporate network.

First VM has Domain controller running and I can log in on that machine using domain credentials. I named domain wm.local
When I run IP config on this machine:
IP: 192.168.87.132
Def Gataway: 192.168.87.2
DNS server: 192.168.87.2
DHCP server: 192.168.87.254

Second VM cannot join domain. When I try it with domain WM I'm propmted for credentials.
And I enter Administrator credentials and than it waits for some time and I get response:
"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"
If i type wm.local as domain when trying to join it does not prompt me to login but just
shows "An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain wm.local could not be contacted. And here it takes no time to get this error message.

Ipconfig on this machine:
IP: 192.168.87.134
Def Gataway: 192.168.87.2
DNS server: 192.168.87.2
DHCP server: 192.168.87.254

I can ping second VM from first one. And I disabled firewalls on both machines.
Any ideas?
Is there any manual for this?

Answer (score 1):

The domain controller should be the DNS server for the domain (Active Directory-integrated DNS).

If the client machine on the domain doesn't use the DC as its DNS it will either take forever for a DC join to happen (as well as domain logons taking forever), or it won't work at all.

In the DC, setup the DNS server (probably already done during DC setup/promotion), and setup a forwarder in the DNS to forward all unknown requests to your ISP DNS.

Then set both VM's to use the DC as their DNS.

Reboot machines and try joining the client to the domain again.

If you want things to be really slick, also use the DC as the DHCP server, and set it up to auto-update the domain DNS for you. :)